# Исправление опечаток в доменах почтовиков

Tags: php

Добрый день!
Многие пользователи на сайте при регистрации допускают опечатки в доменах почтовиков:

```
yndex.ru
indox.ru
yndex.ru
yndex.ru
meil.ru
MAILE.RU
bambler.ru
yndex.ru
ramrler.ru
maiil.ru
yndex.ru
rambker.ru
uandex.ru
```

Как можно их автоматом исправлять на пхп или угадывать правильный домен и переспрашивать пользователя?

Если даже составить небольшой словарик, то как сравнивать опечатки с нужным словом?

Comment: Спасибо за подсказки, попробую совместить оба метода

Answer (score 2):

есть функция, проверяющая доменное имя checkdnsrr, т.е. вполне можно проверять ajax'ом валидность домена и в случае ошибки говорить пользователю, что он ошибается. Сам функционал проверки по сути примерно такой:

```
$result = checkdnsrr(array_pop(explode("@",$email)));
```

Comment: вы удивитесь, но большинство таких доменов в dns есть.

Comment: Но обратите внимание:

> **Примечание:** Эта функция не реализована для платформ Windows.

Так что это только для Linux/FreeBSD сервера.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov Без второго аргумента функция будет проверять именно наличие MX записи в dns. Для элементарной проверки, дойдут ли куда либо письма, адресованные на этот домен хватит. Но в качестве защиты именно от опечаток годится слабо.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

- При регистрации нового пользователя отделяйте от email подстроку, после собаки. и сохраняйте в отдельную, для корректных доменов, таблицу в БД, если полученный домен уникален (можно выбирать домены и из базы пользователей, но такой запрос будет значительно дольше обрабатываться, при большом числе записей).
- Загружая форму, куда надо вводить адрес, выбирайте все домены из базы в массив.
- Проверейте, по событию keyup, содержит ли поле адреса `@`. Если да -- предлагайте варианты из вашего массива, содержащие подстроку, введённую после собаки, за вычетом первого и последнего символов (возможная опечатка).

Это алгоритм, могу подсказать, какими функциями пользоваться, если что-то неясно по реализации.